# handsontable getData returns list, not array

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I'm having issues with my 'local' data collection.  I have a back end system expecting a nested list

```
[[a,b,c],[1,2,3]]
```

I was under the impression that the getData() returned data this way, but it does not.  I get a comma string with no clear denotation of when a row starts.

this is the DOM rendered source after i put in a few a-c's in one row.

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 850px; HEIGHT: 400px; OVERFLOW: visible" id="datatable_1" class="datatable handsontable" jQuery1102047903577534572483="5">

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var colheaders =["x","y","z"];
var dwidth = $("#datatable_1").width();
var data_1 = [["","",""]]; //gives the form shape for default view
var $container = $("#datatable_1");
var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
 $("#datatable_1").handsontable({ afterChange: function () { $("#dt_1").val($container.data('handsontable').getData()); }, contextMenu: false, fixedColumnsLeft:1, minSpareRows:1,stretchH: 'all',width:dwidth,colHeaders:colheaders,rowHeaders:true, data:data_1, minRows: 1, startCols: 82});
</SCRIPT>
<INPUT id="dt_1" type="hidden" name="dt_1" value="a,b,c,,," />
```

So as you can see, i get the comma list as val in my input (which is what i will post as part of a greater form later-- i don't want to use ajax) and my spare row of nothing.   Alerting it returns the same thing.

Since i don't know the shape, this may be 1-6 rows of 6-1 data points each...  36 combos!
Anyone see what i'm missing so i can generate

```
<INPUT id="dt_1" type="hidden" name="dt_1" value="[[a,b,c],[,,,]]" />
```

Comment: you can use JSON.stringify to keep the brackets

Comment: This does seem to work.  Thank you!